# constructor overloading with default value fields

Tags: c#, constructor, overloading, this

How Can send default parameter in Constructor from initial value in field

```
    private readonly string name= "Test";
    private readonly int id= 1;

    public Demo(string name, int id)
    {
            this.name= name;
            this.id= id;
    }

    public Demo(int id):this(this.name,id)
    {
    }
```

I want send the default value of name from field , I Know I can set it by but I think why write default value again in Constructor

```
   public Demo(int id):this("Test",id)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Why not just set `id` in the second constructor, and not call the first constructor at all?

Comment: @RB. Maybe the first overload in the real code does something else in addition to setting properties, and OP doesn't want to repeat that code in the second overload?

Comment: @Sweeper exactly, I want overload and I don't need to repeat code in first contractor to another contractor

Comment: Actually, why initialise the readonly fields at the declaration at all? Remove `= "Test"` and `= 1`, and now you can write `public Demo(int id):this("Test",id)` without repeating `"Test"`.

Comment: @Sweeper but if client create object with two parameter then can't set initial value because we set value in contractor with one parameter

Comment: If the client code creates an object with two parameters, then it would be calling the first constructor, which sets both fields anyway. The initial value doesn’t matter because it will be overwritten.